# undefined symbol at python-aruco error _aruco.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, aruco

I'm building python-aruco.[https://github.com/fehlfarbe/python-aruco/tree/aruco1.3.0]
Installation succeeded.
However, when you start up the sample, you get an error like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 5, in <module>
    import aruco
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aruco.py", line 28, in <module>
    _aruco = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aruco.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_aruco', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_aruco.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5aruco5Debug8setLevelEi
```

The pass is be passed, but what is the problem?

[image]

**Environment**

- ubuntu16.04
- python3.5
- aruco-3.0.11

[image: terminal image]

Comment: Are you sure you pointed the build to appropriate Python header files?

Comment: @sophros
Sorry, I do not know how to confirm..., but setup.py is completed, I think it's okay

Comment: First of all `python3.5 -V` will tell you the exact version of Python you are using. Then check `apt list --installed |grep libpython`. What is the version of the headers you are having.

Comment: And run `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_aruco.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to check the dependencies of the library. Maybe some of them are not satisfied and symlinks would do.

Comment: @sophros
Thank you for the polite explanation. Screenshot added above. Looks like the link is satisfied?

Comment: Yes. All requirements seem to be satisfied. Sorry to say, I have no further ideas.

Comment: @sophros thank you comment, I work hard.